# SOQL SELECT doesn't return all the fields

Tags: php, laravel, salesforce

I'm struggling trying to query more than 3 fields from salesforce.

---

## I try

```
$records = Salesforce::query('SELECT Id, Name, Patient_Status_del__c, DOB__c,Patient_Sub_status_del__c  FROM Patients__c');

dd($records);
```

I got only 3 fields

[image]

---

But when I use the same query in workbench, I got

```
SELECT Id, Name, Patient_Status_del__c, DOB__c,Patient_Sub_status_del__c  FROM Patients__c
```

[image]

---

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure you have read access to all these columns? With the account you are connecting to the database with in your PHP script

Comment: Are you using the same credentials to login to phpMyAdmin as you use in your PHP connection

Comment: Yes. I used the same credential to log-in to `https://workbench.developerforce.com` and set it on my Laravel `.env` file.

Comment: Ok so as I have never used salesforce I am going to bow out here as I have nothing else I can offer I am afraid

Comment: Make sure you've got an upto date WSDL file.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is querying through the API, whereas your second example is directly querying the database.

The issue is the API is not returning all the fields. The API will only return the fields it knows about, so when you add custom fields, you need to update the WSDL so it knows about the custom fields.

Answer (score -1):

Try to put the fields between single quotation marks, in case the query are taken some empty spaces or any other character.

```
SELECT `Id`, `Name`, `Patient_Status_del__c`, `DOB__c`, `Patient_Sub_status_del__c` FROM `Patients__c`
```

Comment: Really just a comment if you think about it! _Who upvotes this sort of answer?_

Comment: Can you please add your suggestion as part of your answer ?

Comment: Yes. The GUI tools like MySQL WorkBench or phpMyAdmin put the fields between single quotation marks.

Comment: @RiggsFolly : Do you know how I should adjust my syntax to be able to query it ? But I used the same syntax in workbench and it works perfectly.

Comment: SELECT 'Id', 'Name', 'Patient_Status_del__c', 'DOB__c', 'Patient_Sub_status_del__c' FROM 'Patients__c'. And check the underlined and the double underlined.

Comment: @JesúsAmieiro Complete and utter ovoid's especially as his query is in a single quotes string

Comment: @ihue I think what he is trying to say is try using backticks around each column name i.e. `'SELECT \`Id\`, \`name\` .....'`

Comment: Ahh... Okay that sounds more legit. I'll try that. :)

Comment: I got `MALFORMED_QUERY: 
SELECT `Id`, `Name`, `Patient_Status_del__c`
^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:7
line 1:7 no viable alternative at character '`'`

Comment: Better edit your question and show exactly you did, add it as an edit at the end

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes, I have take a look at phpMyAdmin and it uses backticks, not single quotation marks. I have updated the query

Comment: @JesúsAmieiro : I'm sorry, I got malform query when use single quote or backticks.

Comment: @ihue try to remove one by one field in the query to detect  the problematic field

Comment: These 2 fields `Patient_Sub_status_del__c` + `Patient_Status_del__c`never show up no matter what !